# Yii2 Kartik DatePicker - Date should not exceed current date

Tags: datepicker, yii2

Is there a way in kartik DatePicker Yii2 - by which I can disable the dates that are greater than current date?
For example: if today is 14th march 2016 then calendar dates from 15th march 2016 should be disabled.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plugin Demo [page](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker) says "DatePicker widget is a Yii2 wrapper for the Bootstrap DatePicker plugin". So you can use all bootstrap datepicker options in this plugin.It should come under "pluginOptions" as key value pair.

"endDate" => "0d", // Will disable all dates after today.

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
  'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
  'pluginOptions' => [
      'autoclose'=>true,
      'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
      'endDate' => "0d"
  ]
]);
```

[Bootstrap Datepicker Doc](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)

Comment: Glad to help. In most of the cases , everything we need to know is already in the docs.Give them a chance and you will be astonished by the result :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery 
these tutorials will help you : http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

Comment: I wish i could. But I am restricted to kartik date picker due to some requirements. Thanks for your response.